# Splunk search events

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

For events format:

```
LogMessage: { [-]
 message: { [-]
   data: { [-]
     ConnectorRequest details:
       request: { [-]
         application: bond
         items: [ [-]
           { [-]
             naturalKey: ************4206
             system: debitCard
           }
         ]
       }
       url: https://token-service.apps.cloud.com/v1/tokenization
     }
   }
}
```

I can use search:

```
index="0010-pcf-abc-service*" | search "LogMessage.message.data.ConnectorRequest details.request.items{}.naturalKey"="************4206"
```

and it returns results with specific naturalKey value.

Similar search for all events with specific url value:

```
index="0010-pcf-abc-service*" | search "LogMessage.message.data.ConnectorRequest details.url=https://token-service.apps.cloud.com/v1/tokenization"
```

returns zero results but in reality, there are thousands of such events in the index.

Why is that?

Comment: That's not valid JSON

Comment: I think I shouldn't stress JSON format in this question as I can specify the other field in the similar fashion and it return results. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a few problems at play here.

Firstly, your second search structure does not match your first one. The `| search` command needs to be structured as follows:

```
| search "complex key"="complex value"
```

Not:

```
| search "complex key=complex value"
```

Note the difference in quotation-marks.

Secondly, you might be hitting field extraction limits. To address this, you can either force a JSON field extraction using `spath` or modify your limits.conf.

Spath example:

```
index="0010-pcf-abc-service*"
| spath "LogMessage.message.data.ConnectorRequest details.url"
| search "LogMessage.message.data.ConnectorRequest details.url"="https://token-service.apps.cloud.com/v1/tokenization"
```

You can read more about limits.conf in [Splunk's documentation](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Limitsconf#.5Bkv.5D).

Comment: If the `search` command consists of a single quoted string then Splunk will search events for that *exact string*, including any embedded equal signs.